# Android MediaPlayer RTSP Unknown Error

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

We're working on an app that will stream live video from an IP Camera send over the RTSP protocol.

The stream works fine on only one of our devices (LG G2 - KitKat 4.4.2). However when we try running it on any of our other devices (Samsung S3, S4, Note 3, Nexus 5) it fails with this error: `E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)`

Research on the interwebs tell us that this means the actual error is unknown, which  is a bit frustrating. Can anyone please help us with this. Here's some of the code that initialises the stream:

First, our `surfaceCreated` method:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait.." , "Connecting.." , true);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    new PrepareStreamTask().execute();

}
```

Then an AsyncTask to prepare the stream:

```
private class PrepareStreamTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {

        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentStream.getUrl());
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result){
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

As you might have guessed the error happens on the `prepareAsync()` method. We have also tried using `prepare()`.

The stream itself is setup like this:

Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 320x240, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc

Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s

Can anybody please shed some light on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use the Vitamio Library. Everything works well now, on all devices.